# CModel subclass in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a 4 days old yii fan and I like it so much.

I have a special database table that can't be used by CActiveRecord directly. My solution is to subclass CModel to have my own logic for listing, creating, saving and deleting records. My new CModel subclass cant not instantiated;  it seems that CModel requires more methods to be defined to allow creating an instance from it.

My question is: Is this the right approach to go or there are better ways? If yes, what are the missing methods to define to make my new class complete; not abstract

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine generally speaking, and would be fine even if you were not "forced" to adopt it. I use a `CActiveRecord` subclass as the base for my models to provide additional custom functionality.

As for your other question, you only need to implement `attributeNames()` to be able to instantiate objects of your class.

However, why do you not subclass `CActiveRecord` directly instead of `CModel`? You can still override any and all methods you choose to. Is your database so dramatically different from the usual schemas that you won't be able to reuse any of the logic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I could (finally) recognize from sources that attributeNames is the only virtual method in yii. I just don't like to use CActiveRecord because it does not bring any added benefit to me while my (virtual) record is stored many records rather than one in a kinda of attribute:value table

Answer (score 2):

I usually create my own classes to handle the so called 'logic' of the webapp that I'm building.

I place it in another folder (usually the logics folder) and auto import the directory from the config. The logic classes doesn't subclass from any Model

```
public class ProfitLogic { ... }
```

where inside the class(es) I implement functions that instantiates and use any ActiveRecord(s) that I need.

The reasoning for this is that when prototyping I often refine my database design, and I need to regenerate the ActiveRecords again :p

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to Yii as well, but have found that extending CForm, as in the default ContactForm model can be useful.

Not the best for having lots of heavy business logic, but it touches on your point of breaking out of the typical workflow.